# what happens if the argument structure for a subclass constructor call does not match it's superclass constructor

Tags: java, inheritance, constructor, super

1. If you have a subclass and your subclass only constructor is `super(int x, int y)` but that argument structure does not match any of it's superclass constructor's argument structure, what happens at that point? How does the subclass invoke it's superclass constructor?
2. Is the default constructor of `super()` used in this circumstance?

or

1. Is the default constructor used ONLY if there is no call to `this()` or `super()` as the first line of a subclass?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You have to call directly to the `super contructor` that you prefer, except the super has a "visible" constructor without parameters.
2. Only if it is accesible (public or protected) and there is no other constructor matching with its signature.

**Samples:**

---

Parent constructors:

```
public Parent();
public Parent(int x, int y);
```

Child Constructors:

```
public Child() {
   // invokes by default super() if there is no other super call.
}

public Child(int x, int y) {
   // invokes by default super() if there is no other super call.
}
```

---

But if you define the **parent constructor as private**:

Parent constructors:

```
private Parent();
public Parent(int x, int y);
```

Child Constructors:

```
public Child() {
   // does not compile due there is no "visible" super().
}

public Child(int x, int y) {
   // does not compile due there is no "visible" super().
}
```

You need to invoke the super constructor directly

```
public Child() {
   super(1,2);
}

public Child(int x, int y) {
   super(x,y);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The SuperClass constructor is called from the SubClass constructor in the following pattern.

**1** > 
SuperClass does not have a default constructor, which means SuperClass has a constructor with arguments. eg

```
SuperClass(int a){
     //somethin
}
```

you must explicitly call super class constructor from the subclass constructor(s) otherwise it your program will not compile. ex.

```
Subclass(){
      super(10);
}
```

**2** > SuperClass has a default constructor which could either it does not define any constructor or defines a default constructor. In this case you don't need to call the super constructor from subclass one, but you can if you want by calling.

```
 Subclass(){
     super();
  }
```

Keep in mind that you can only have one call to another constructor from any constructor. 
ex.

```
SubClass(){
   super();
   this(10);//this will not compile either you can call this or super
}
```